# DDE: Time series in Excel analysis

Tags: excel, matlab, time-series, dde, algorithmic-trading

Summary:
I need to store/analyze a live time-series that comes into 1 cell in Excel using DDE.

Problem:
Since it is 1 cell that is constantly changing, I don't know how to grab each instance of the updated value so I can use it in other formulas, plots, etc.  So its 1 cell in an Excel spreadsheet which changes every millisecond, and I want to get the actual time-series (t,t-1, t-2, t-3, etc).  I don't know how to store as a time series.

Detail:
I am using MetaTrader 4 (MT4) to develop some analysis.    The codes to import live prices look like this:

```
=MT4|BID!EURUSD
=MT4|ASK!EURUSD
=MT4|HIGH!EURUSD
=MT4|LOW!EURUSD
=MT4|TIME!EURUSD
```

I want to be able to use the time series in various formulas to calculate and update plots in real-time. If I could send the live data to MATLAB, that would be helpful also. But it all has to be live data in real-time analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to a VBA solution, you can use the `Workbook.SetLinkOnData` method to call a Sub when the incoming data changes.

I would suggest only responding to changes on the `TIME` topic, and copying all relavent data in one go

Based on this data layout

[image: Based on this data layout]

Set up the monitor on the Open event (place this in the `ThisWorkbook` module)

```vb
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Links As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Links = wb.LinkSources(xlOLELinks)

    For i = LBound(Links) To UBound(Links)
        If Left$(Links(i), 8) = "MT4|TIME" Then
            wb.SetLinkOnData Links(i), "MT4_OnUpdate"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And code your data handler in a normal module

```vb
Sub MT4_OnUpdate()
    ' DDE Updated TIME, copy data
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Your DDE Data Sheet")

    With ws
        Set Source = ws.Range("A2:E2")
        Set Dest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, Source.Columns.Count)
    End With

    Dest.Value = Source.Value
End Sub
```

This will copy cells `A2:E2` to the bottom of the Historical data list, each time `A2` (time stamp from MT4) changes.

Note: you say in your OP that you want to update every millsecond.  This can't happen, because `MT4|TIME` is returning a DateTime serial which has a resolution of 1 second.  And even if it could happen, that would be way too much data for Excel to handle

Comment: This is really helpful.  I haven't used VBA in a while but I will give this a shot and see how I do.  Really appreciate the detailed response.

Comment: Would you be willing to code this up for a fee? I can't get it to work.

Comment: I think you should stick to SO for now.  Post another question, be sure to [follow the guidlines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/159408) in particular post the code you have tried and explain how it doesn't do what you want.  Include a sample data set showing input and output sample data. I'll help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the platform of FxOne.com.
You can try for 30 days free.
If you are a client of FXCM then is totally free.

It is more powerful than excel because don't use the VBA but the C++ which is perfect for algorithmic trading. VBA is very good for analysis but not for trading. I tried to do what exactly looking for and everytime Excel was crashing. With this platform everything was very smooth.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. This is a really cool platform and I will definitely look it over in more detail.